# Show basic inequality for complex random variables

Tags: statistics, expected-value, jensen-inequality

Suppose I have $n$ (not independent) complex random variables $X_i,i=1,\ldots,n$. I want to show the following
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_{j=1}^nX_j\right|^2\right]^{1/2}\leq \sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{E}[|X_j|^2]^{1/2}.
\end{equation}
I suppose it's somewhat immediate from applying Jensen's inequality in a clever way, but haven't been able to figure it out by myself. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about Cauchy-Schwarz and Beppo-Levi?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: This is the triangle inequality on $L^2$.

Comment: Ooooooh! Right, it's just immediate once you noticed that the guy on the LHS is the definition of the $L_2$ norm for random variables. Thanks!!